# html5 required and jQuery submit()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to implement html5 into a form, but I came with a problem when I submit the form through jquery and try to use the html5 "required" attribute.

Here is my form, quite simple:

```
<form action="index.php" id="loginform">
      <input name="username" required placeholder="username" type="text">    
      <a href="javascript:$('#loginform').submit();">Login</a>
</form>
```

The problem is that when the form is submited through jquery, It just by-passes the required attribute. I know that required should only work if the form is submitted by the user, not by a script, so when I change the anchor to a submit input it works perfect.

My point is if there is a way to force the jquery .submit() to use html5 required atribute.

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: If all your users are using Chrome you can use the `checkValidity` method. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Spb/) - too bad IE is still faaar behind.

Comment: Why are you using a link, not a submit button?

Comment: 'My point is if there is a way to force the jquery .submit() to use html5 required atribute.'. His form is most likely just to illustrate the issue without further complicating the issue.

Comment: Good question and good try

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I did the following

```
<form>
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="hide"></button>
</form>

<script>
    ...
    $(...).find('[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
    ...
</script>
```

¡it works!

Comment: `class="hide"` or `style="display:none"`

Answer (score 39):

You can

- trigger `click` event on a submit
- check validation manually with `$("form")[0].checkValidity()`
- find invalid elements manually using `$("form :invalid")`

Answer (score 6):

Here an exemple of my personnal solution:

```
var form = $('#loginform');

// Trigger HTML5 validity.
var reportValidity = form[0].reportValidity();

// Then submit if form is OK.
if(reportValidity){
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right. HTML5 validation works only when submit is triggered by user. this is how it is. :(

you need write a your own custom method on submit. OR there is a good plugin you can use which  validates fields according html5 attributes.

[here is the plugin link](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/)

Answer (score 2):

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30124479/7915308

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="testform" action="action_page.php">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" required><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:console.log(document.testform.reportValidity());return false;">Report validity</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:console.log(document.testform.checkValidity());return false;">Check validity</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(document.testform.reportValidity()){document.testform.submit();}return false;">Submit</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.  I had a single button that I had deliberately set NOT to be a submit because it was on first click revealing a form.  On a second click of the same button $('form[name=xxx]').submit(); was firing and I found as well that the HTML5 validation doesn't work.

My trick was to add a line of code so that after my first click of this button occurs I change its type to submit dynamically.

```
$("#btn").attr("type","submit");
```

Which worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function instead and use that function to check if all the nodes with the required attribute have a value.

There are some plugins available to do this: http://thechangelog.com/post/1536000767/h5validate-html5-form-validation-for-jquery

Comment: im aware of that, Im trying to use jquery and html5 together, as I want to be html5 my main validator

Comment: There are some plugins available.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples, how to validate html5:

```js
function validateForm(form) {
  if (form.username.value=='') {
    alert('Username missing');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" name="loginform" method="post" onsubmit="if (!validateForm(this)) event.preventDefault();">
  <input name="username" placeholder="username" required="required" type="text" />
  <a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); $(document.forms.loginform).submit();">Login1</a>
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="$(document.forms.loginform).submit();">Login2</a>
  <input name="send" type="submit" value="Login3" />
  <input name="send" type="button" value="Login4" onclick="$(document.forms.loginform).submit();" />
</form>
```

Full code [here](http://pastebin.com/4EuVaviR).
One thing here is strange: $(document.forms.loginform).submit(); works fine, but document.forms.loginform.submit(); fails. Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score -1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3gFmC/

Hope this will help `:)`

**code**

```
$('#btn_submit').bind('click', function() {

        $('input:text[required]').parent().show();
        // do whatever;
 });
```

​