# Submitting a form with JQuery - Required Fields

Tags: jquery, html, web, submit, required

I'm trying to submit a specific form Using the following command:

```
$("#formName").submit();
```

Definitely that's working, but, I have required fields into the form, and if those're empties it's not throwing the alert message.
Any ideas around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround your `$("#formName").submit();` in an if statement that checks the (length of) the values in your required fields, that way the form will only submit if those values are present.

You could go one step up and use separate methods for validation that return a boolean, and only if all validation methods return true do you submit the form.

Comment: Alright... but I mean, is there a way to do that automatically for required fields (like a Submit input does)?

Comment: How are you designating your fields as required?

Comment: According to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381369/html5-required-and-jquery-submit) jQuery doesn't properly support the HTML5 "required" tag yet, and you'll have to implement your own solution or use a jQuery plugin.