# Javascript .submit() overrides required field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that I want a modal to confirm before sending. I do this with JavaScript. I open the Modal and there I use the `.submit()` function but it sends the form without respecting the "required" fields.

Here's an example I made with **http://www.w3schools.com/**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="some" action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('some').submit();">Send anyway</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/fmpk1h1m/**

What I want is the same effect of the `required` attribute whether I send the form directly or by JavaScript.

Comment: the w3c demo has the same problem that you are suffering from. for some reason the JavaScript submit bypasses the html5 required attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

Comment: If `Element.value === ''` then they didn't fill it out. Get used to doing everything AJAX, as well. Just a tip for the future.

Comment: You should not rely on client-side validation either way. The best thing to do would be to make a custom validation function to call, or call the click event of the submit button as many people have suggested, and then make sure you are using server-side validation to catch anything that gets through. Client-side validation can be easily bypassed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 required and jquery submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381369/html5-required-and-jquery-submit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trigger the form submit button click:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
var sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');

sendButton.addEventListener('click', send);

function send(e) {
    submitButton.click();
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/8rwfspbt/1/**

Comment: Whoever downvoted, mind elaborating on why this does not answer the question?

Comment: Thanks, it's not quite what I need but you pointed me in the right direction. I'll let you know how it works. :)

Comment: great answer, have similar issue

Answer (score 0):

`.submit()` won't check the `required` HTML attribute. You can achieve something similar by simulating a click event using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('btn').click();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84o9jvft/)

Comment: *"`.submit()` won't check the required HTML attribute."*: Source?

Comment: @Felix I don't have a source, but FF 61 does not do the check.

Answer (score -3):

Put the button into the form itself, no javascript required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="some" action="demo_form.asp">
   Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>

   <p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in     Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You should use the `input type="submit"` in your form instead of creating a button outside the form for it.

Comment: I _need_ to make the submit from outside the form. Thanks.