# Required is not working in html 5 when form submitting through jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Required property is not working in html page.I make my submit button to not allow double clicks with JQuery.It works fine but required is not working if user submitting the form with empty fields.How to solve this?For all help thanks in advance.

Here my code is:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnSubmitInTimesheet').on('click', function() {
    console.log("inside clickkk");
    $(this).val('Please wait ...')
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout('$("#btnSubmitInTimesheet").removeAttr("disabled")', 1000);
    $(this).val('Submit')
    $('#timesheetForm').submit();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
  <input type="text" required>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitInTimesheet">
</td>
```

Comment: have you included jquery validation libraries?

Comment: yes jquery works also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 required and jquery submit()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381369/html5-required-and-jquery-submit)

Answer (score 0):

From [html5 required and jquery submit()](/questions/11381369/html5-required-and-jquery-submit)

It looks like any call to either form.submit() or form.trigger('submit') through jQuery will circumvent the required field checking.  I fixed it by replacing the submit button with normal button and hiding a separate submit button so it's onclick could be triggered via jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click","#btnSubmitInTimesheet",function(e) {
        $(this).val("Please wait ...").attr("disabled","disabled");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).val('Submit');
            $("#btnSubmitInTimesheet").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#realSubmit").trigger("click");
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Html body:

```
<body>
<form id="timesheetForm" action="someOtherPage.html">
<input type="submit" id="realSubmit" style="display:none">
<input type="button" id="btnSubmitInTimesheet" value="Blah?">
<input name="foo" type="text" required>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @dnvsp Your code uses Scala which I don't have, so I couldn't run your code even if it was an [mcve], which it isn't.  I'll edit the answer to include a full on click handler.

Comment: @dnvsp Your setTimeout seems invalid.  The way you have written it will set up the timeout, change the button to read 'Submit' (but it will still be disabled) and then immediately submit the form.  Assuming the form has an action set, the browser will immediately navigate away from the page and the timeout will never occur

Comment: @dnvsp Try now.  This ended up being harder than it appeared at first glance- looks like something the jQuery folks should take a look at, although there it probably a better way to fix it - hiding submit buttons is pretty kludgy (which is also a duplicate: [jQuery submit() doesn't call html5 validation](/questions/19280685/jquery-submit-function-doesnt-call-html5-validation))

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#btnSubmitInTimesheet').click(function(){
  console.log("inside clickkk");
  $(this).val('Please wait ...').attr('disabled','disabled');
  setTimeout('$("#btnSubmitInTimesheet").removeAttr("disabled")', 1000);
  $(this).val('Submit');
  $('#timesheetForm').submit();
}
```

Try this one.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

put this in header

Comment: Do you include jquery libraries properly?