# Two button submit form issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hi successfully made a form where there are two submit buttons.

I needed two buttons because I need each button to take the form to a different place, while get/post the information in the first form.

This is how I did it

Javascript:

```js
 function submitForm(action) {
    var form = document.getElementById('form1');
    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" >
    <div class="f-row">
  <label for="pick">Pick-Up Address</label>
  <input type="text" input name="pick" required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pick']) ? $_POST['pick'] : ''; ?>"/>
   </div> 
  <input type="button" onclick="submitForm('page2.php')" class="btn small color left" value="ADD ANOTHER STOP" />
  <input type="button" onclick="submitForm('page3.php')" class="btn medium color right" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

It works, both buttons submits to the relevant pages.

But now there is one problem I can't seem to fix, previously if the form was not filled, and i clicked submit, it would ask me to fill up the required fields, now it does not anymore.

If required fields are not filled up, it still submits the form.

I need button 1 to not require required fields to be filled up, and button 2 to require it as button 2 submits the form, while button 1 brings it to a new form to fill up with other details before they submit from there.

Anyone know of a way I can sort this?

Comment: Use jquery to check if input is filled or not.

Comment: you need to use custom jquery validation to validate your form. add condition if form1 is submitted to skip jquery validation other it check validation and show the message.

Comment: you have to validate the form (hopefully you are doing it with jquery validation) inside `submitForm` function.

Comment: button1 on click validate the form then return false if not submit

Comment: You're just missing the `required` attribute in your input field.

Comment: @omerowitz sadly `required` does not always work. I can't tell you which browsers/code it doesn't work with, but in the past i used `required` as well, but failed sometimes.

Comment: Add a submit button and hide it, then when you click on either of your visible buttons, click the submit button. Like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856220/submit-html5-form-using-javascript-and-validate-its-inputs). Seems the HTML5 form requires a submit input element inside the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use jquery to validate the form when the first button is clicked and you can use `formaction` attribute on the button to specify where the button should go when it's clicked.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

  $('#btn1').on('click',function(){

   var pick = $('input[type="text"][name="pick"]').val();

   if(pick == ""){
    alert("enter pick");
    return false;

   }else{

    $(this).submit();
   }
  });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" method="post" >
    <div class="f-row">
  <label for="pick">Pick-Up Address</label>
  <input type="text"  name="pick" value="your value">
   </div> 
  <button type="submit" formaction="page2.php" class="btn small color left" id="btn1">ADD ANOTHER STOP</button>
  <button type="submit" formaction="page3.php" class="btn medium color right">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow this actually worked. It asked both buttons to key in required fields, but i worked around by using my original code for button 1, and your formaction= code for button 2. and it works perfectly. Will test it on other browsers as well. Thanks

Comment: Glad could help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: `<input type="text" name="pick" id="pick" required/>` and in the javascript

```
function submitForm(action) {
            var form = document.getElementById('form1');
            form.action = action;
            if (document.getElementById('pick').value) {
               form.submit();
            }}
            else{
            alert('Please fill the required field!');}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jQuery` for this.

```
if ($('#something').length)
```

This will check if there exist an element with the id `'something'`, but not if it is empty or which value it has.

To check this you can use:

```
if($('#something').val().length>0)
```

or

```
if($('#something').val() != "")
```

Do with it what ever is needed.

You could even add this check within your `submitForm` function just above the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(action) {
        var a = $("input[name=pick]").val();
        if(a) {
            var form = document.getElementById('form1');
            form.action = action;
            form.submit();
        } else {
            alert('please fill the required field');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: his worked. now it asked both forms to fill up required field, however it appears as a popup on the whole browser, instead of previously it appears as a bubble over the form field input itself. Any idea why?

Comment: @DilMarc, change button type ="button" to type = "submit" to show validation error in form field.

Answer (score 0):

**Using this way(simple way):--**

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" onSubmit="encriptar_rc4();return false;">
<input type="submit" name="submitOne" value="submitOne" class="submitButton" />
<input type="submit" name="submitTwo" value="submitTwo" class="submitButton" />
</form>

<script>

$(function(){
  $(".submitButton").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr("name"));
    
  });
  
  encriptar_rc4();{
  alert('hola');
}
  
});

</script>
```