# Default 'input is required/Please fill out this field' message doesn't show after using an icon inside input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

So I have this form where there is an input field that needs to be filled to submit the query. I haven't used a button to submit the form but instead used a font awesome icon inside the input field. And with Javascript I made the form submit if a user clicks on the icon.

It works perfectly as I wanted but the only issue is the form submits even if the field is empty. The `required` attribute isn't working, probably because I'm not using a button. So to stop the form to be submitted without a value I used an if statement to check if there's any value and using an alert instead of a message to the user if there's not. But I want to display the default message to the user which the browser shows that the field is empty. How can I display the default message to user if the field is empty in this situation?

Please note that I'm using node and express for the app and ejs as my template engine. The javascript code is in `main.js` file the public folder and not in the script tags inside the template.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchIcon").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$("#input").val()) {
      alert("input empty");
    } else {
      $("#form").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" />
<form id="form" action="/submit" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="input" name="search" required>
  <i id="searchIcon" class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit HTML5 Form using Javascript and validate its inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856220/submit-html5-form-using-javascript-and-validate-its-inputs)

Comment: The problem looks like your if statement is not evaluating correctly, try $('#input').val() != '' || $('#input').val() != null. Also i would think about giving the element a proper id too (just a suggestion)

Comment: hi. ummm it says to add a hidden submit button. but my form is submitting. the issue is the if the field is empty i want to display the default message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `checkValidity()` and `reportValidity()` methods of the `form` to trigger the default HTML5 validation:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $form = $('#form');
  
  $("#searchIcon").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (!$form[0].checkValidity()) {
      $form[0].reportValidity();
    } else {
      $("#form").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" />
<form id="form" action="/submit" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="input" name="search" required>
  <i id="searchIcon" class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</form>
```

However it should be noted that your code does not meet accessibility validation requirements due to the lack of a submit button.

You can easily include one, and thereby remove the need for any JS code, by styling it to look like the FontAwesome icon:

```css
button.submit {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" />
<form id="form" action="/submit" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="input" name="search" required>
  <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: hey the first code worked. The second thing which you wrote, is that a big of a deal? can I just keep it like that? The thing is I'm using the icon inside the input field. I don't think I can use a button inside the input field. Right?Sorry don't judge me if it's a noob question.

Comment: It's a big deal if you need to meet certain web standards. `The thing is I'm using the icon inside the input field. I don't think I can use a button inside the input field` The icon is outside the input - as it has to be. You cannot place any other HTML element inside an input (unless you mean that you're repositioning using CSS). The button works in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory. I tried the icon with the button and I think I can place it inside the input field. Thanks again.